# C++ - Operator overloading and inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, operator-overloading

I need help with operator overloading and inheritance.

```
class A {
public:
    virtual bool operator==(const A& a);
};

class B : public A {
public:
    bool operator==(const B& b) { ... }
};
```

I want to be able to do something like this. The problem lies in the argument to the operator. I want to only be able to take in a B in the B class but I can't because of the original overload. How do I solve this?

Comment: *"I want to be able to do something like this."* - That's a problem in itself. Why would you need this? It basically leads to the issue of double dispatch; i.e. the desired implementation of the function no longer depends on the dynamic type of *one but of *two* objects. Getting this right costs a lot in terms of development complexity, and gains little. If I were you, I'd just remove the operator entirely.

Comment: If you don't want to compare an `A` with a `B`, why has `A` provided a virtual `operator==()` in the first place?

Comment: I want to be able to have a list of A and be able to perform the operation on B and C.

Comment: @Znatte: Do you care for the `B` and `C` portions of the objects if you compare two `A`s?

Answer (score 0):

Operators are just functions, so your issue is not related to them. What you want here is called multiple dispatch (double, in this particular case, as Christian correctly mentioned). There are multiple approaches in terms of implementation and run-time complexity, including ones that require language support (see e.g., virtual function parameters and the corresponding paper from Bjarne Stroustrup).

If you want to do this in core C++, you're welcome to take a look at my generic implementation and copy what's needed:
https://ideone.com/uGue2K

Usage of the code:

```
// C inherits from A, both have a static initializer that registers them and their base class(es)

struct print : Visitor2<A>
{
    // Feel free to change the return type, but keep it consistent.
    // Alternatively, you can call a lambda with the result.
    static void v1(const A& a1, const A& a2, int i, int j)
    {
        std::cout << "A, A: "<< a1() << a2() << " " << i << " " << j << std::endl;
    }

    static void v2(const C& c1, const A& a2, int i, int j)
    {
        std::cout << "C, A: "<< c1() << a2() << " " << i << " " << j <<  std::endl;
    }

    // and so on...

    print(int k_)
    : k(k_)
    {
        add_visitor( v1, v2 /* ... */ );
    }

    auto operator[](const A& a) { /* see in code */ };
};

int main()
{
    print p(4); // p takes virtual A&, virtual A&, int, int.

    const A& a = A();
    const A& b = B();

    p[a][a](1, 2);
    p[c][a](2, 3);
}
```

Suggestions are welcome on the code and the pattern. To make it easier to follow, `operator[](const A&)` of the visitor is implemented in-place, but it could be done entirely in `Visitor2<A>`.

Note that you can't just have `Visitor< Visitor<A> >` in place of `Visitor2<A>` as that wouldn't 'backtrack' to the outer resolver when there are multiple outer matches and the inner one tried first fails. This highlights the difficulty of multiple dispatch (that Christian mentioned): you need to see all the potential functions globally. Expect slowness and large compilation units; only implement if it's in specs and no shortcuts are found.